# jquery width() method always updates the initial width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to javascript and jquery. I need help to understand the following block of code:

An unordered list with 4 list items:

```
<ul>
  <li id="one" class="hot"><em>fresh</em> figs</li>
  <li id="two" class="hot">pine nuts</li>
  <li id="three" class="hot">honey</li>
  <li id="four">balsamic vinegar</li>
</ul>
```

The following is the jquery code -

```
$('li').width('50%');
$('li#two').width('75%');
```

I expect the width of the second list item to be 75% of 50% of the initial width (on page load). However, the width is only 75% of the initial width. I thought the first `jquery` statement affect the next one?

Comment: why not use css to set the width?

Comment: try following way $('li').css('width','50%');
$('li#two').css('width','75%')

Comment: Try using google before SO. Width in % refers to parent width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you specify percentage width, the percentage refers to the width of the parent (the `ul` in your case) and not the previous `li` width you have set. In other words, `li#two` is not a subset nor a child of `li`. What you can do is declare the initial width as a variable then use multiples of it, something like:

```
let originalWidth = 0.5;
function getPercentWidth(width) {
    return ((width * 100) + '%');
}
$('li').width(getPercentWidth(originalWidth));
$('li#two').width(getPercentWidth(0.75 * originalWidth));
```

Comment: Are you sure that percentage width refers to the parent width, and not the current width of the `li` (because `width` is not an inherited property) ?

Comment: When you provide a percentage width, you immediately ask the question: percentage of what ? And the answer is: the parent's width. Here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/glouhaichi/pen/RLvyoE) illustrating the behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. My confusion was due to the fact that I was changing the width set by CSS using jquery. But it is clear now.

Answer (score 2):

This is the correct behaviour of `jQuery.width()` method. The code you should use is like this:

```
$("li#two").width($("li#two").width() * 0.75);
```

Because you need to get the 3 quarters of the current width. Not the initial width.